# Print request in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

```
 def test4(request):
   logging.debug(request)
   logging.debug(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])
   return render_to_response('test2/test4.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In the above code can request be printed in the test4.html and also the request.META['HTTP_REFERER'] i had tried

```
      <script>

        alert('{{request}}');    //prints empty
        alert('{{request.META.HTTP_REFERER}}');  //prints empty

      </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added `django.core.context_processors.request` to your context processors setting? [It's not enabled by default](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request).